# Relation between the events in future. Is it possible to connect present continuous and simple future

Tags: future-tense, present-continuous, future-continuous

I wanted to ask you whether the following sentence construction is allowed or not:

> I will find that I am correcting myself.

For the clarification I am putting the context bellow:
I know that in future I will correct myself. Or in future, When I will be correcting myself that time I will realize that I am correcting myself. To make it generalize, could I make such sentences where first past is simple future and second part is present continuous where both will indicate future incidents.Sorry, It was hard to describe the events sequence but I think I am clear to you.

> If I made any mistakes in the question then please mention it in the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your sentence is grammatically correct and natural.

Yes, you can use future simple and present continuous to make sentences of this kind. The usage of future simple puts the moment that you find, see, realise, understand into the future. The use of present continuous indicates that you find, see, realise, understand **in the middle of** the continuous activity.

Here is another example.

> One day, you will realise that you are getting old.

If you use the past continuous for the second verb, it places the continuous activity before the moment of realisation (and could even be before now).

> One day, you will realise that she was lying.

If you use future continuous for the second verb, it places the continuous activity after the moment of realisation.

> One day, you will realise that you will soon be getting old.